# JQuery File Upload Plugin (BackLoad): How to limit # and size of files?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using JQuery File Upload plugin with BackLoad for uploading files in MVC4 application. The upload works fine. However, I could not figure out a way to limit the # and size of files. Can we do this in the plugin?

Now, user can add as many files (images) as they want and file size can be very large. I only want to allow them upload 1 file and size < 10MB at a time.

I tried to change the **template-upload** to show just one file, but it does not work. It seems when multiple files are selected, the **template-upload** will be used multiple times. Each time, **files** only has one file.

I also changed **maxFileSize** in **Backload.Default.config**, but it does not work. It seems it is for images that are already uploaded.

Before I used Ajax toolbox in web form, and they can be done easily. Now, I'm trying this in mvc4 application, any idea of how to achieve these?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113424/using-backload-to-store-files-in-database). Setting property maxFileSize: 5000000, //5mb will affect it on client side.

Comment: anyway to limit the # of files to be uploaded?

Comment: i can assume, if you remove property 'multiple' from <input type='file' id='fileUpload' /> it can make some result. Or you can check length of Request.Files on server side.

Comment: If you want, please add it as answer. I'll accept it. For limit # of files, actually, it has a property: maxFileNumber:1 , it does the work.

Comment: actually, it is maxNumberOfFiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting properties maxFileSize: 5000000, //5mb 
and maxNumberOfFiles: 1
will affect it on client side.